# Нет вебхука в списке хуков в МС, а при добавлении пишет что он есть

Tags: moysklad-json-api

Получаю все хуки по адресу https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/entity/webhook
В списке нет ничего связанного с приемкой(supply)

Делаю попытку установки webhook путем POST запроса, получаю ошибку:

```
{
    "errors": [{
        "error": "Ошибка сохранения webhook: webhook с данным набором параметров уже существует",
        "code": 30003,
        "moreInfo": "https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/doc#обработка-ошибок-30003",
        "line": 1,
        "column": 2
    }]
}
```

Как быть?

Comment: @IvanPivkin Пожалуйста, обеспечьте поддержку.

Comment: Возможно на другой странице. Если не сможете найти, обратитесь в поддержку

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте limit, offset и size в запросе на получение списка хуков.
Максимальный limit=100, дальше только листать offset`ом(100, 200, 300 и т.д.)

[image: проверьте limit, offset и size]